# Translating bitwise comparison from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

I've the given condition from a cpp source.

```
if (!(faces & activeFace) || [...]) { ... }
```

I want to translate this into C#.

When I understand this right, this means as much as `if activeFace is *not* in faces then...` -  not?

So what would be the equivalent in C#?
Note: I can't use `faces.HasFlag(activeFace)`

Well it should be

```
if ((faces & activeFace) == 0 || [...]) { ... }
```

**Am I right?**

For the completeness here the actual Flag enum

```
[Flags]
enum Face {
    North = 1,
    East = 2,
    South = 4,
    West = 8,
    Top = 16,
    Bottom = 32
};
```

Well It's the same in cpp, you just need to add a `[Flags]` attribute in C#

Comment: Removed your awkward line. Not relevant and imho the question is not awkward but something good to know for beginners

Comment: What data types are faces and activeFace?

Comment: `Am I right?` Yes. Question solved?

Comment: this is fairly easy to test. Did you try anything prior to asking?

Comment: You don't actually have to add the `[Flags]` attribute in C#. Your code will work just fine without it.

Comment: @Default I've never used cpp. And on windows it's not as easy as `apt-get install gcc ; gcc test.cpp` (or whatever the actual command would be) - so: no.

Comment: @Brettetete FYI, there are online compilers to easily test code, for instance http://ideone.com/ or https://dotnetfiddle.net.

Comment: @Jashaszun: It is a good practice in C# to add a `FlagsAttribute` when the enum is used as flag, i.e. if its constants are powers of 2, as this expresses the intention of the programmer. The attribute also influences the way `ToString` works and produces a neat output if flags are combined. This is useful when debugging.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Oh wow! I've been programming in C# for years and I didn't know that `[Flags]` changed `ToString()`! I guess you learn something new every day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would add a value `None = 0` to the enum

```
[Flags]
enum Face {
    None = 0,
    North = 1,
    East = 2,
    South = 4,
    West = 8,
    Top = 16,
    Bottom = 32
};
```

and then test

```
if ((faces & activeFace) == Face.None || otherExpr) {
    ...
}
```

A good reason to add a `0` constant to an enum is that class fields are zeroed by default and omitting a `0` constant would lead to enum values not corresponding to any enum constant. It is legal in C# to do that, but it's not a good practice. C# does not test whether values assigned to enums are valid enum constants.

But if you cannot change the enum, you can cast the enum value to `int`

```
if ((int)(faces & activeFace) == 0 || otherExpr) {
    ...
}
```

And yes, in C++ any `int` unequal `0` is considered as Boolean `true` value, so `!(faces & activeFace)` in C++ means: *activeFace is **not** in faces*

Comment: Well, it seems you put all the other answers out of contention. Thanks for your extensive answer, here your well deserved +1 ;)